# Split a string at the first occurence of a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I've tried multiple solutions from other threads but nothing seems to work when the split flag is a string as well. In this case I need to separate the first " - " (space dash space) from the rest of the string, which contains other occurences of " - "

`var string = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum";`

Looking for a resulting array of:

`[1][000 : 3 - loremipsum]`

Comment: You could try using substring with indexOf(‘ - ‘).

Comment: can you clarify your expected output please? `[1][000 : 3 - loremipsum]` isn't an array, did you mean `[1, "000 : 3 - loremipsum"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by `" - "` to get an array of the form:

```
["1", "000 : 3", "loremipsum"]
```

Then you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to separate the first element and the rest of the array (`r`) from each other, and use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to form a string, with the rest of the array (`r`) [joined](http://JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) back together with a hyphen:

```js
const string = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum";
const [first, ...r] = string.split(" - ");
const res = `[${first}][${r.join(" - ")}]`;
console.log(res);
```

Or if you want your result in an array, you can create an new array rather than using a template literal:

```js
const string = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum";
const [first, ...r] = string.split(" - ");
const res = [first, r.join(" - ")];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple replace() will suffice if you want that expected output

```js
var str = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum"
console.log('['+str.replace(' - ', '][')+']')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using substrings since you seem to be a beginner in javascript.

```
var string = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum";
var start = string.indexOf(" - "); // find the first ocurance of space dash space
var result = [];
result.push(string.substr(0, start)); // string before " - "
result.push(string.substr(start+3)); // string after " - "
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the best and easiest to understand answer yet! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split on your delimiter and then join all the elements after the first element:

```
const string = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum"

const delimiter = " - "
const splitArray = string.split(delimiter)
const firstElement = splitArray[0]
const otherElementsJoined = splitArray.slice(1).join(delimiter)
const finalArray = [firstElement, otherElementsJoined]
console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `match()` here:

```js
var string = "1 - 000 : 3 - loremipsum";
var first = string.match(/^(.*?) -/)[1];
var second = string.match(/^.*? - (.*)$/)[1];
var output = [first, second];
console.log(output);
```